# Is it possible to mount a gzip compressed dd image on the fly?

Tags: dd, compression, disk-image

I like to create an image backup the first time I'm backing up a system. After this first time I use `rsync` to do incremental backups.

My usual image backup is as follows:

- Mount and zero out the empty space:

  ```shell
  dd if=/dev/zero of=temp.dd bs=1M
  rm temp.dd
  ```
- Umount and `dd` the drive while compressing it

  ```shell
  dd if=/dev/hda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c  > /mnt/sda1/hda.ddimg.gz
  ```
- To put the system back to normal, I will usually do a

  ```shell
  gzip -dc /mnt/sda1/hda.img.gz | dd of=/dev/hda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K
  ```

This is really straightforward and allows me to save the 'whole drive' but really just save the used space.

Here is the problem. Lets say I do the above but not on a clean system and don't get the `rsync` backups going soon enough and there are files that I want to access that are on the image. Let's say I don't have the storage space to actually unzip and `dd` the image to a drive but want to mount the image to get individual files off of it.... Is this possible?

Normally, one wouldn't compress the `dd` image, which will allow you to just mount the image using `-o loop`... but this isn't my case...

Any suggestions for mounting the compressed img on the fly?

Would using [AVFS](http://avf.sourceforge.net/) to 'mount' the gz file then mounting the internal dd.img work (I don't think so... but would need verification...)?

Comment: You should use `SquashFS` for this kind of things. It also de-dupes duplicated files.

Comment: It looks like this fellow is doing what you are asking about:
http://blogs.gnome.org/muelli/2012/10/loopback-monting-huge-gzipped-file/

Comment: I second Avio's suggestion. The only thing squashfs doesn't archive is acls. It archives xattrs, so selinux attributes, etc. If you don't use acls, then squashfs is the way to go IMHO. I've recently had to archive "just in case" some old drives that have already been migrated to new storage, and squashfs was perfect for the job.

Comment: Also, this is possible without restrictions for `.vhd(x)` images. These are quite common in the Windows world and the full solution for mounting can be found here: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/mount-virtual-hard-disk-vhd-file-ubuntu-linux/?unapproved=516&moderation-hash=6ecfb4ca6f97ff53d32570f3ba2e28f0#comment-516

Comment: You can also consider this short anser: https://askubuntu.com/a/252719/830570 and this Q/A: https://superuser.com/a/1097391/910769

Comment: `conv=sync,noerror` is a really bad combination. Any read error will pad the remainder of the block with zeros, and then `dd` will attempt to reread from where it left off. You've now got a partial block of zeros somewhere in your data _in addition to_ the data you've successfully read. Just use `cat`

Comment: Regarding the OP's original command to decompress to stdout, I think "gunzip -c" and "gzip -dc" operate similarly (but are technically two different programs). I wasn't paying close enough attention and ran "gzip -c" on the decompression step, which is clearly wrong. It writes a further compressed output to the drive. It wouldn't hurt for a naïve individual to decompress even using "gunzip -dc" with the -d just being redundant, but the other way is a problem. For safety reasons, it might be reasonable to just always add the -d parameter, regardless of gzip or gunzip.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It depends on whether the disk image is a full disk image, or just a partition.

### Washing the partition(s)

If the disk is in good working condition, you will get better compression if you wash the empty space on the disk with zeros. If the disk is failing, skip this step.

If you're imaging an entire disk then you will want to wash each of the partitions on the disk.

**CAUTION:** Be careful, you want to set the `of` to a *file* in the mounted partition, *NOT THE PARTITION ITSELF!*

```shell
mkdir image_source
sudo mount /dev/sda1 image_source
dd if=/dev/zero of=image_source/wash.tmp bs=4M
rm image_source/wash.tmp
sudo umount image_source
```

### Making a Partition Image

```shell
mkdir image
sudo dd if=/dev/sda1 of=image/sda1_backup.img bs=4M
```

Where `sda` is the name of the device, and `1` is the partition number. Adjust accordingly for your system if you want to image a different device or partition.

### Making a Whole Disk Image

```shell
mkdir image
sudo dd if=/dev/sda of=image/sda_backup.img bs=4M
```

Where `sda` is the name of the device. Adjust accordingly for your system if you want to image a different device.

### Compression

Make a "squashfs" image that contains the full uncompressed image.

```shell
sudo apt-get install squashfs-tools
mksquashfs image squash.img
```

### Streaming Compression

To avoid making a separate temporary file the full size of the disk, you can stream into a `squashfs` image.

```shell
mkdir empty-dir
mksquashfs empty-dir squash.img -p 'sda_backup.img f 444 root root dd if=/dev/sda bs=4M'
```

### Mounting a compressed partition image

- First mount the `squashfs` image, then mount the partition image stored in the mounted `squashfs` image.

  ```shell
  mkdir squash_mount
  sudo mount squash.img squash_mount
  ```
- Now you have the compressed image mounted, mount the image itself (that is inside the `squashfs` image)

  ```shell
  mkdir compressed_image
  sudo mount squash_mount/sda1_backup.img compressed_image
  ```
- Now your image is mounted under `compressed_image`.

EDIT: If you wanted to simply restore the disk image onto a partition at this point (instead of mounting it to browse/read the contents), just `dd` the image at `squash_mount/sda1_backup.img` onto the destination instead of doing `mount`.

### Mounting a compressed full disk image

This requires you to use a package called `kpartx`. `kpartx` allows you to mount individual partitions in a full disk image.

```shell
sudo apt-get install kpartx
```

- First, mount your squashed partition that contains the full disk image

  ```shell
  mkdir compressed_image
  sudo mount squash.img compressed_image
  ```
- Now you need to create devices for each of the partitions in the full disk image:

  ```shell
  sudo kpartx -a compressed_image/sda_backup.img
  ```

  This will create devices for the partitions in the full disk image at `/dev/mapper/loopNpP` where `N` is the number assigned for the loopback device, and `P` is the partition number, e.g. `/dev/mapper/loop0p1`. You can find this number `N` in the output of `losetup --list`. The most recently created loopback device should have the largest `N` number.
- Now you have a way to mount the individual partitions in the full disk image:

  ```shell
  mkdir fulldisk_part1
  sudo mount /dev/mapper/loop0p1 fulldisk_part1
  ```

Comment: interesting take on this problem (squashfs instead of gzip). I am pretty unfamiliar with squashfs tools... can you pipe the output of dd to create a squash partition on the fly as you can with the gzip partition? what is the compression ratios (gzip is okay/good, esp given the fact that I am clearing 'empty space with zeros')?

Comment: how would you dd the image back to the hard disk?

Comment: @g19fanatic The uncompressed disk image is "inside" the squashfs image. You mount the squashfs image, then dd the image inside it to the destination disk.

Comment: @g19fanatic The compression was excellent (very nearly the same as gzip in my case). mksquashfs was fast too, it is parallelized. On my 990x (6 core) it was actually limited by the destination disk write speed, around 100MB/sec.

Comment: @g19 The point of the extra effort of wrapping the uncompressed image in a squashfs is being able to mount, browse, and read from the image without unzipping it and without having to have the space to unzip it.

Comment: @g19fanatic I don't know a way to "stream" into a squashfs. squashfs tries to eliminate duplicate files and optimizes the directories etc (unnecessary when it holds a single disk image file btw), which it can't do on the fly. Perhaps it is possible to stream into a squashfs, I don't know.

Comment: @g19fanatic You can stream into squashfs using the `-p` or `-pf` flags to pass it a pseudo-file. A pseudo file can be used for things like making device nodes which you can't otherwise do without root (useful for building images as part of a build process) or for streaming the output of some command into the image. One of the examples given in the docs (`/usr/share/doc/squashfs-tools/examples/pseudo-file.example` on Debian/Ubuntu) is `input f 444 root root dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=1024 count=10` to copy the first 10K from a disk image into a file named "input" in the squashfs image.

Comment: I use `dd if=/dev/sdX bs=4M iflag=direct | pigz --blocksize $[4*1024] -9 -p 4 > BACKUP.gz` for backup any disk/partition. - I have replaced `gzip` with `pigz` (fork of `gzip`) for compression uses all cores of my CPU.

Comment: Usually `mksquashfs` uses zlib compression (that is the one gzip uses). But you can change that using the `-comp` option. Compressors   available: gzip (default), lzma (no kernel support), lzo, lz4 and xz.

Comment: Of course you can also send the image with ssd such as `| ssh <USER@HOST> 'cat - > filename.img'` and compress it on the go with gzip like 'gzip -c' but that is another story.

Comment: Does washing still have an advantage with encrypted images? The blocks aren't zero but they should all be the same right?

Comment: @jiggunjer I doubt it would compress. I would expect the encryption to vary for every block. I would also expect the same block to be completely different if you moved it to another cluster, but I am not sure.

Comment: if you're using an SSD, I would advise being sure you can TRIM the drive if you fill it with zeroes like this, to mark all blocks unused. Don't delete the wash file until after DDing, so that you can TRIM it afterwards, because reading unused blocks will cause the SSD to mark the the block as all zeroes and in use.

Comment: A good explanation of the mksquashfs command arguments can be found here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/836217/how-to-mount-a-compressed-disk-image

Comment: An alternative to zero-filling the rest of the partition is to shrink the partition to the smallest size a partition resizing tool will let you shrink it to, then image it (you can resize the partition back up to its previous size after).  Zero-filling an entire drive has the potential to prevent some SSD optimizations, plus it requires a lot of writing.

Comment: `mksquashfs` procedure worked great for streaming compression for a partition.  For unknown reason (got a permission denied error), I needed to specify `read-only` to mount the inner partition.  I.e., using the example above, I needed to use `sudo mount -r squash_mount/sda1_backup.img compressed_image`.

Comment: @HackerBoss Thanks for that link! Was looking for a simple breakdown of the arguments and their meaning for the `-p` flag.

Comment: This answer is very interesting but it would be a lot better if it had explanation as to why writing an image into a squashfs image is a good idea.

Comment: `cat` could also be considered instead of `dd` - [check this](https://tecmint.com/backup-or-clone-linux-partitions-using-cat-command)

Answer (score 37):

Try [`archivemount`](https://www.cybernoia.de/software/archivemount.html)

```
root@srv1:/backup# archivemount windows-2003-S.gz /target/
Unrecognized archive format

root@srv1:/backup# archivemount -o formatraw windows-2003-S.gz /target/
Calculating uncompressed file size. Please wait.

root@srv1:/backup# ls /target/
data

root@srv1:/backup# file /target/data
/target/data: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0x7, start-CHS (0x0,1,1), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 63, 58717512 sectors, extended partition table (last)
```

archivemount is a FUSE-based file system for Unix variants, including Linux. Its purpose is to mount archives (i.e. tar, tar.gz, etc.) to a mount point where it can be read from or written to as with any other file system. This makes accessing the contents of the archive, which may be compressed, transparent to other programs, without decompressing them.

http://linuxaria.com/howto/how-to-mounts-an-archive-for-access-as-a-file-system

After mounting archive you can use it contents like regular file. Maybe get partition table, or convert, mount image with qemu tools.

squashfs useful for booting from image, but much complex for backuping.

Comment: Perfect! This is the most easy and elegant solution so far. I wonder why there are no votes here.

Comment: I think it is because if you mount an archive like disk.img.gz on a folder with archivemount, say /mnt/, you would get a single file /mnt/disk.img, that you then have to mount elsewhere. The question instead wants something able to unwrap both in a single step (and archivemount seems capable to do that on .tar.gz, but not on gzipped raw images).

Comment: @p91paul squashfs method is same with packing in tar.gz in this case. You can mount squashfs, but you also can mount tar.gz and skip ten steps in creating image and have 1-two step to see contents

Comment: Of course, but still the original question doesn't talk about a tar.gz. My point was to tell @TranslucentCloud this answer has no votes because it doesn't actually answer the question, it tells "you should have created a tar.gz instead"

Comment: @p91paul fair enough. But still the eri's answer sheds light on some interesting tool.

Comment: This answer is not for votes. It shows some point of view on actions in question.

Comment: Right, but do not forget, that Stack Exchange network is not designed to merely help to original question posters, but also to strangers, who stumble upon a similar problem. If they have a similar, but slightly different problem and if the solution is worth a considering, they could vote up the corresponding answer.

Comment: I had *similar* problem and found this page.

Comment: This answer is very interesting too. I believe squashfs gets more love because it has more awareness. I instantly recognized the name but have never heard of archivemount. I will have to give it a shot too!

Comment: archivemount does not allow to mount an image created by command `dd if=/dev/hda conv=sync,noerror bs=64K | gzip -c  > /mnt/sda1/hda.ddimg.gz`

Comment: `name@hozd ~ $ archivemount /tmp/test.ddimg.gz /tmp/t
Unrecognized archive format
name@hozd ~ $ archivemount --version
archivemount version 0.8.5
FUSE library version: 2.9.4
fusermount version: 2.9.4
using FUSE kernel interface version 7.19`

Comment: Agreed - at time of writing, archivemount supports tar archives that are gzipped, but not plain gzipped files.

Comment: @Sergei, @mwfearnley, @g19fanatic  - i added example with `dd ...| gzip > raw.gz` image what works

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: @eri it not works, it mount data which can't be mount as loop, this should not be accepted andswer!

Answer (score 21):

If the image is *read-only* you can also use [**nbdkit**](https://github.com/libguestfs/nbdkit) ([man page](https://github.com/libguestfs/nbdkit/blob/master/docs/nbdkit.pod)) and its [**xz**](https://github.com/libguestfs/nbdkit/blob/master/filters/xz/nbdkit-xz-filter.pod) filter (xz should provide better compression and random access times than gzip). If you need ***temporarily*** write access, the [**cow**](https://github.com/libguestfs/nbdkit/blob/master/filters/cow/nbdkit-cow-filter.pod) (Copy On Write) filter might be useful.

##### Create the compressed partition image

```sh
dd if=/dev/sda1 bs=16M | xz -9 --block-size=16MiB > sda1.img.xz
```

A `--block-size` option of 16 MiB should provide good random access performance.

Note: you may use alternative xz compression programs such as [**pixz**](https://github.com/vasi/pixz) which provides parallel compression, just make sure it splits the output in multiple small blocks, otherwise **nbdkit** has to decompress a lot of data. For example as of September 2015, [**pxz**](http://jnovy.fedorapeople.org/pxz/) does not support this.

##### Serve it with nbdkit

```sh
nbdkit --no-fork --user nobody --group nobody -i 127.0.0.1 \
       --filter xz file sda1.img.xz
```

##### Connect to the NBD server

```sh
nbd-client 127.0.0.1 10809 /dev/nbd0 -nofork
```

##### Mount it read-only

```sh
mount -o ro /dev/nbd0 sda1
```

##### When done

```sh
umount /dev/nbd0
nbd-client -d /dev/nbd0
```

Stop the **nbdkit** server by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (or with **kill**).

Comment: See also for 'Viewing a gz / xz Compressed dd image "on-the-fly"': https://askubuntu.com/questions/836217/how-to-mount-a-compressed-disk-image/859410#859410

Comment: See also for "Mount zip file as a read-only filesystem: fuse-zip, archivemount, fusermount": https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168807/mount-zip-file-as-a-read-only-filesystem

Comment: Also you can see "Archival filesystem or format: virt-sparsify, guestmount, qcow2 gzip, ndbkit xz plugin, read-only mksquashfs": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6147303/archival-filesystem-or-format

Comment: Addendum 1 `guestfish` for mounting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138367/318461 - Addendum 2 `nbdkit`: "specify the block size": https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/405820/318461

Answer (score 12):

This answer complements [Cristian Ciupitu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138081/73177).  **If** you use xz compression with a reasonable block size, you can access the disk image using [guestfish](http://libguestfs.org/guestfish.1.html) or other [libguestfs](http://libguestfs.org/) tools like this:

```
nbdkit xz file=disk.img.xz --run 'guestfish --format=raw -a $nbd -i'
```

**UPDATE**: Since xz is not a plugin anymore, but has become a filter, the command is now:

```
nbdkit file disk.img.xz --filter xz --run 'guestfish --format=raw -a $nbd -i'
```

Comment: See original answer is better: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31669/is-it-possible-to-mount-a-gzip-compressed-dd-image-on-the-fly/138081#138081

Comment: Guestfish is nice and can also be used for `.vhd(x)` files without restrictions, they are pretty common in the Windows world. For the full solution on mounting look here: https://www.how2shout.com/linux/mount-virtual-hard-disk-vhd-file-ubuntu-linux/?unapproved=516&moderation-hash=6ecfb4ca6f97ff53d32570f3ba2e28f0#comment-516 (I expect this to also help here as guestfish is discussed in detail)

Answer (score 11):

Not really.  You can't really seek to a specific block in the compressed file without decompressing the whole thing first, which makes it difficult to use the compressed image as a block device.

You could use something like `dump` and `restore` (or `tar`, really), all of which use a streaming format...so you can access invidividual files by effectively scanning through the uncompressed stream.  It means if the file you want is at the end of the compressed archive you may have a long time to wait, but it doesn't require you to actually decompress everything onto disk.

Using `tar` for backups may seem a bit old fashioned, but you get a lot of flexability.

Comment: The problem lies in the fact that I do not even know if the file of interest is actually on this compressed backup... Do you know of a file explorer that will go through the whole .gz'd image, keep the file/dir structure in memory, provide a simple view of the structure and allow you to 'pick' files (now that it knows where they exist) to extract?  Its a very niche specification... but I could see tons of uses for something like this... if it exists.

Comment: If it doesn't, would you be able to point me towards some instruction on how to pull the structure from the gz'd image? I would be able to create such a program (program for a living...) but am blind on the topic of decompressing image data and the specifics of different filesystems.

Comment: I suspect that building your own tool is going to be  a larger project than you really want to undertake.  However...assuming that you have an ext[234] filesystem, I would suggest the [e2fsprogs](http://e2fsprogs.sourceforge.net/) package, or maybe something like [fuse-ext2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/fuse-ext2/).  Both provide user-space tools for interacting with ext[234] filesystems.

Comment: Also note that what you have doesn't appear to be a filesystem image, it's a whole disk image, which means you'll first have to parse out the partition table and locate the appropriate partition.

Comment: I mistyped in the above question and will fix it. I usually do a partition based dd image and save a copy of the partition table. I used to do whole disk copies but hated needing to mount with options to get to the proper location.

Comment: Looking through some of the documentation for tar, e2fsprogs and fuse-ext2, I'm not seeing how I can take the gz img and use these programs to even search for one file in an on-the-fly manner.

Comment: You can't.  You were suggesting you were going to write your own tool.  These projects provide examples of code that interacts directly with ext[234] filesystems.  I believe your only practical solution is to unpack the image onto disk or onto a `tmpfs` filesystem if you have the available memory.  `tar` would only help if you had a compressed `tar` archive instead of a filesystem image -- I had suggested that as a more flexible solution than using filesystem images.

Answer (score 3):

Another addendum to [Cristian Ciupitu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138081/34653):

If you use `nbdkit` to mount a **full disk image** (vs. a partition image), you might need to specify the block size (sector size of the disk) when connecting to the NBD server, as it defaults to `1024` bytes. To use `512` bytes instead:

```
nbd-client 127.0.0.1 /dev/nbd0 -b 512 -n
```

After that, the disk will appear as `/dev/nbd0`, and you should be able to view the partition table using `fdisk -l`. However, the partitions are not yet mountable - Use `kpartx` (from [doug65536's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75590/34653)) to create devices for the partitions, e.g.:

```
kpartx -arv /dev/nbd0
```

Finally, the partitions will appear in `/dev/mapper/`, and you can mount them as usual. Make sure to use readonly mode (`-o ro`), as the xz plugin only supports reads:

```
mount -o ro /dev/mapper/nbd0p3 /mnt
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [AVFS would work](https://blogs.gnome.org/muelli/2012/10/loopback-monting-huge-gzipped-file/).

First you create a "portal" over your filesystem where all operations performed on your files are intercepted through the AVFS FUSE system:

```bash
~ $ mkdir avfs                # the AVFS mount-point
~ $ avfsd -o allow_root avfs  # Needs `user_allow_other` option in /etc/fuse.conf
~ $ cd avfs
~/avfs $ ls  # your root filesystem listed
```

Then attach [a loopback device with partition table](https://superuser.com/questions/211338/how-to-mount-a-multi-partition-disk-image-in-linux) on the transparently uncompressed disk-image located in the `~/avfs` mount-point:

> **ℹ️ Note:** the `#` character suffix is not a comment but part of [the AVFS-syntax](https://github.com/glycerine/avfs/blob/master/avfs-1.0.3/README) that uncompresses the file.

```bash
~/avfs $ sudo losetup -Pf ./absolute/path/to/full-disk.img.gz#
/dev/loop0
```

The command above selected and printed the first unused loop-device.

The kernel has now created additional loop-devices for all the partitions contained in the `full-disk.img.gz`.  You can mount them the usual way:

```bash
$ sudo mount /dev/loop0p1 /some/mount/point/
```