# Hour glass/Progress while extracting large file from remote host in shell

Tags: shell-script, zip, progress-information

I have a shell script, which is using `unzip` to get a very huge file from a remote directory to local directory within the shell. This operations taking pretty long time, roughly from 20-30 min.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

…

unzip RemoteHostNFSDirectory -d LocalHostDirectory > output.log
```

(it is a 6.2 GB file).

How can I embed the above command in a progress or hour-glass bar so users don't think that it is just hanging and once extract to the local directory is done successfully. I can print success or failed error.

(Newbie to shell, apologize for any inconvenience.)

Answer (score 0):

#### Preliminary note

Displaying "a progress or hour-glass bar so users don't think that it is just hanging" regardless if `unzip` is not hanging would be quite easy. In this answer I assume you don't want to mislead users. The answer tries to show the progress of `unzip`, not just a fake indicator.

---

#### Most straightforward method

If your `unzip` [can read from stdin](https://superuser.com/a/1372548/432690) and you want to extract the whole archive then measure progress when reading the archive:

```
< /path/to/archive.zip pv | unzip -
```

<sup>`pv` can be replaced by any tool that displays progress information and passes the data through.</sup>

---

#### Other general methods

If your `unzip` cannot read from stdin but you're sure there is just one file in the archive and you know the name you want to use for the extracted file, then extract to stdout and pass through `pv` to get a progress indicator:

```
unzip -p /path/to/archive.zip | pv > /extracted/name
```

If there may be more files in the archive then you need to specify a single file to extract:

```
unzip -p /path/to/archive.zip internal/path/to/compressed/file | pv > /extracted/name
```

Extracting many files with a single `unzip -p` will concatenate them in `/extracted/name`. To extract more than one file run `unzip` many times, redirecting to different pathname each time.

If you don't know internal names then you need to parse `unzip -l` or `unzip -v` beforehand. This way you can also learn the uncompressed size, if you want to use it with `pv -s`. I admit I don't know how stable and parsable (unambiguous) in general these formats are.

With `unzip -p` you won't get any log from `unzip`. Rely on its exit status. If you need some kind of log then the shell script itself should write to it. The script must know at least the `/extracted/name`, so it can log at least this.

---

#### FUSE?

I expect any [FUSE-based solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/168807/108618) to allow you to use any tool able to copy a regular file. The progress bar can then depend on the tool. The command may be as simple as:

```
pv /mountpoint/internal/path/to/compressed/file > /extracted/name
```

This won't necessarily help you. I tested `fuse-zip`. It seems it extracts (to a temporary file or in memory, whatever) before the actual copying tool can start its job. So the actual extracting is still without any progress indicator; the chosen tool can only indicate copying of an already extracted file later. Caching a "very huge file" has its own problems, I'm not sure if and how the tool tries to solve them. Irrelevant, because `fuse-zip` cannot solve your original problem anyway.

I also tested `archivemount`. The progress bar of `pv` started immediately but the whole setup was painfully slow. I discovered `archivemount` jumps (seeks) within the archive back and forth even if the reading process reads sequentially. Probably this will be unpractical for your "very huge file". *Maybe* some tweaks are possible, maybe I missed them.

---

#### Trick with `pv`

A clever but somewhat cumbersome method is with `pv -d`:

```
unzip /path/to/archive.zip > output.log &
pv -d "$!"
wait "$!"
```

The method should be fine to make "users not think that it is just hanging", although in its basic form it will show users more than you probably want. Some options of `pv` or even "manually" parsing `/proc/$!/fd` and `/proc/$!/fdinfo` without `pv` may help.

`unzip` working in the background will not be able to get response from the user easily, so consider `unzip -o` (with caution).

`pv` will terminate after `unzip` terminates, so there is no need for `wait` if you want to strictly wait. `wait "$!"` is there to return the exit status from `unzip`.

Comment: Hello Sir,  I am on RedHat 7.8 and pv is not available or not even option as it is not part of standard corporate build.  I was thinking of some kind of spinner or hour-glass to roll/rotate while the files are getting extracted.   Although "pv" looks like pretty simple and handy.

Comment: @NaveedIftikhar In this case `pv` (but not `pv -d`) can be replaced by any tool that displays progress information and passes the data through. Is `mbuffer` available? Does your `dd` support `status=progress`? Or is `ifne` available? (it does not print progress but can be used to create a tool that does). With `tee` the tool does not even need to pass the data through. "What to use instead of `pv`?" and "how to make `unzip` work with `pv` or like?" are different questions. This site works best when there is one question per question. But I'm willing to help, just answer my questions.

Comment: @NaveedIftikhar `some kind of spinner` – If the input is of undetermined size (and this is the case when reading from a pipe, unless you use `-s`) `pv` displays a progress indicator that moves back and forth. `pv -p` displays the indicator only. It's not that different from a spinner. Or did you mean a spinner in GUI?

Comment: Sir Kamil,    No in GUI  just on simple bash shell.    I was able to create a spinner (google the great) and was able to implement it.  Appreciate all of your input and help.   Thanks a lot.