# Mounting zip files (plural)

Tags: mount, compression

I know I can mount a single zip file as a directory for read-only access ([Mount zip file as a read-only filesystem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/168807/mount-zip-file-as-a-read-only-filesystem)) but if I have a directory (or a directory tree) containing many zip files, is there a way to mount it as an unzipped directory tree ?
For instance:

```
A/AAA.zip
A/BBB.zip
B/0123.tgz
B/2345.gz
```

would be seen as:

```
A/AAA/file1
A/AAA/file2
A/BBB/bigfile
etc...
```

I'm trying to convince the organizers of the data to unzip everything to a compressed partition so it would use basically the same space but be a lot easier to retrieve, but just in case there is a way to do this, I'm interested.

Comment: Yes, there is a way. If you know how to do it once, you should be able to loop over the zip files and mount each one ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I recursively grep through compressed archives?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13749/how-do-i-recursively-grep-through-compressed-archives)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered [AVFS](http://www.boomerangsworld.de/cms/avfs/index.html) which seems to do what I want. You just run `mountavfs` and then find unzipped versions of the file in a filesystem hierarchy in `~/.afvs`