# Work with compressed dd images

Tags: centos, compression, disk-image

How can I compress dd images and work with them at the same time?

On Windows, I can mark it as compressed and work with it like a normal file.

I can't re-partition, but I can mount some drives (For example `NTFS/Win32`)

Comment: You could try `fusecompress` but you'd have to compile it yourself. It didn't work for me, but I never applied much effort to be honest. YMMV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Linux module](http://knoppix.net/wiki/Cloop) called `cloop` (compressed loop), packaged along with some [corresponding utilities](https://packages.debian.org/stable/misc/cloop-utils), e.g. on Debian.

You can mount these images in compressed state. Caveat: Read-Only.
Also, you have to specifically create them, sda1.img.gz wont just mount.

In an nutshell:

```
# create_compressed_fs - blocksize < /dev/xyz > imageName.cloop
# insmod cloop.ko file=/path/to/imageName.cloop
# mount -o ro -t whatever /dev/cloop /mnt/compressed
```

You could convert an existing image with this as a first step:

```
# gunzip oldImg.gz |create_compressed_fs - blocksize > imageName.cloop
```

Attention: Make sure you have enough Virtual Memory. (see [README](http://knoppix.net/wiki/Cloop))

About the achievable Compression ratio: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloop:

> A compression ratio of about 2.5:1 is common for software. The Knoppix cloop image, for example, is 700MB compressed and around 1.8GB uncompressed.

This module has seen multi-year production use, due to its use e.g. on the [Knoppix Linux live Boot-Disk](http://www.knopper.net/knoppix/index-en.html). [Packaged/updated regularly since 2005](https://packages.qa.debian.org/c/cloop.html). Software seems mature,  e.g. `README` was last modified 2008,

Another popular choice for an overlapping group of use-cases: [Squashfs](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/squashfs), since [2010](https://packages.qa.debian.org/s/squashfs-tools.html).

[Here is a similar Q](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/31669/127903), with a [nice writeup of a squashfs example](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/75590/127903).
It comes down to installing `squashfs-tools` and running

```
# mkdir empty-dir
# mksquashfs empty-dir squash.img -p 'sda_backup.img f 444 root root dd if=/dev/sda bs=4M'
# mount squash.img /mnt/compressed
```

Comment: Unfortunately, available on Debian doesn't necessarily mean available on CentOS (and vice-versa); just as in this case, where `cloop` isn't in the CentOS repos.

Comment: `yum search cloop` returns `Warning: No matches found for: cloop`.  This message is quite common in the RHEL/CentOS world as they are quite conservative when it comes to selecting packages for inclusion :-(

Comment: @garethTheRed that's one of the reasons why i use ubuntu when name/brand recognition is required (for suits) and debian otherwise.

Comment: How far will Fat32/NTFS compression work?  Can I perhaps compress it in Windows, and then use it ro in Linux?

Answer (score 2):

I suppose that `dd image` means a compressed copy of some partition that contained a filesystem.

In general, you can't mount such a compressed image, as it is not suitable for random access. You would need to decompress it, then you can mount it and access the filesystem.

If you want a filesystem which compresses data automatically (like the `Windows` filesystem you mentioned) have a look at `BTRFS`. But to use that, you need to create a partition, so it might not be an option for you.

Comment: squashfs is a compressed filesystem with good random access, albeit read-only (which may be all that's needed in this case).

Answer (score 1):

To create a compressed image on the fly:

```
gzip < /path/to/inpurt >/path/to/image.gz
```

To read a compressed image on the fly:

```
zcat /path/to/image.gz > /path/to/output
```

Comment: There's no need for the `dd` in these cases. Use `gzip </path/to/input >/path/to/image.gz` and `zcat /path/to/image.gz >/path/to/output` directly.

Comment: Naturally.  I've adjusted my answer to no longer use `dd`, which I mainly kept because it was referenced in the original question.