# Zipped hard drive image very big

Tags: compression, disk-image

I just made an image of a freshly installed dual boot (Ubuntu and Windows) using this command (which I've been using for a while for smaller images):

```
dd if=/dev/sda | gzip > /mnt/drive.img.gz
```

On this drive less than 60G out of 500G are used. Nevertheless that image-file now is 409G big.

How is that? Shouldn't gzip manage to compress all those zeros? As I said, it is a freshly installed system. It couldn't be that cluttered.

Now I didn't expect for the file to be 60G, but 400G seems very huge to me.

Comment: ... what zeroes?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

> How is that? Shouldn't gzip manage to compress all those zeros?

Yes, *if they were zeroes*.

Unused disk space does not mean it contains zeros; it means it is unused, and may contain *anything*.

There are programs that wipe unused disk space to zeroes. I suggest you use those before making the disk image. (I don't recall any offhand; in Linux, I'd just use `dd if=/dev/zero bs=1048576 of=somefile` to create files containing only zeroes, filling up each filesystem; then remove them before making the image. Also, I prefer `xz` over `gzip`.)

Comment: Oh thanks, I didn't even think about what was on that drive before I installed it! I guess it's faster to unzip that image now and make that smaller (to which there seem to be solutions as well). I'll also consider using xz. Thanks!

Comment: Writing 400G of zeros every time you want to make a clone does not seem a good idea on a SSD. The other solution (using a filesystem-aware cloning program) seems better.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: No, but the generated image is a perfect [raw disk image](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/disk_cloning). [Disk cloning utilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_disk_cloning_software) use various formats, so you need the utility to restore the image. I am not aware of (but also have not checked if) any that can actually generate a raw image while replacing unused blocks in the image with zeroes; that would be truly useful. Using `dd` in Linux is the simplest and easiest to fix the raw image size issue, and as an one-off, is okay even on an SSD.

Comment: @NominalAnimal Is there a way to use a gzipped disk image without first decompressing it anyway? As far as I know, `gunzip drive.img.gz | mount -o loop -` doesn't work, nor does any other command I can come up with. If the answer is no, then `gzip` is just another special format that one has to decompress before using it.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni: Yes, both gzip and xz -compressed images [can be mounted](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/138367/157724) using [nbdkit](https://github.com/libguestfs/nbdkit). (I'm not really worried about the formats, if they are open and supported by more than one utility; I'm only worried about utilities becoming unmaintained and buggy on new systems. I'd be happy to use [SquashFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SquashFS) instead of xz or gzip, for example.)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni On an SSD, you'd trim.

Comment: @Gilles Trimmed space, when read, is not guaranteed to have zeros. Some controllers give that, others don't.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni It's not a "special" format, in that it doesn't require a very specific program to decompress - it's a very common interchange format. (It's "special" as far as the loop device driver is concerned, though)

Answer (score 14):

For backups of individual partitions you could use [partclone](http://partclone.org/usage/partclone.php) instead.

Partclone reads the file system to see where files are stored, and backs up only those parts of the partition.

Comment: Also, [Clonezilla](http://clonezilla.org/) is an excellent GUI to do this.

Comment: partimage  is an excellent tool, and is in many linux distros/live CDs already.

Comment: Another tool in this vein is `fsarchiver`.