# Inspect/browse gzipped dd disk image from command line without decompressing and mounting?

Tags: command-line, cygwin, disk-image, msys

I did a disk image, as per [How to dd a remote disk using SSH on local machine and save to a local disk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/132797/how-to-dd-a-remote-disk-using-ssh-on-local-machine-and-save-to-a-local-dis) :

```
ssh user@remote "dd if=/dev/sda | gzip -1 -" | dd of=image.gz`
```

Now, I would just like to doublecheck this image - see the partitions included, possibly see files on the partition. However, I would also want to do this under either Cygwin or MSYS2, so I'd want to avoid mounting, and use some sort of a command line tool to inspect/browse the gzip compressed dd image.

From this question:

[Is it possible to mount a gzip compressed dd image on the fly?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/31669/is-it-possible-to-mount-a-gzip-compressed-dd-image-on-the-fly)

... I learned about http://libguestfs.org/guestfish.1.html "a shell and command-line tool for examining and modifying virtual machine filesystems." - which looks like exactly what I need. Unfortunately, it is not available for Cygwin or MSYS2 as a binary (and I tried building from source, and cannot do it).

So I was wondering: limiting myself only to expected swap or ext2/ext3 partitions in the disk image, and gzip compression, and only read-only browsing, - is there any other command-line way to inspect partitions and files in `image.gz` from the command line, without decompressing to a new file and mounting; especially one that might work in Cygwin or MSYS2?